# Using Bokeh datetime with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, bokeh

Is it possible to create the xaxis in a Bokeh chart without using pandas?
Can I just import the Python datetime module to create the xaxis?

In the Bokeh documentation they show this:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL

df = pd.DataFrame(AAPL)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

output_file("datetime.html")

# create a new plot with a datetime axis type
p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250, x_axis_type="datetime")

p.line(df['date'], df['close'], color='navy', alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```

I am trying something like this:

```
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from datetime import datetime

p = figure(plot_height=400, plot_width=1200, x_axis_type="datetime")

p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(hours=["%H:%M:%S"],days=["%H:%M:%S"],months=["%H:%M:%S"],years=["%H:%M:%S"])
```

The code runs but I do not see any x or y axis.

Comment: Do you mean that second block is *all* the code you are trying? Because that creates a completely empty plot (i.e. what you are seeing is entirely expected). By default Bokeh auto-ranges based on the data. If you don't set any data, there is nothing to set the ranges => empty plot. You can set the ranges manually if you want an empty plot with just an axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using pandas:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import AAPL
import datetime

output_file("datetime.html")

AAPL['date'] = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d").date() for x in AAPL['date']]

p = figure(plot_width=800, plot_height=250)
p.xaxis[0].formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter()

p.line(AAPL['date'], AAPL['close'], color='navy', alpha=0.5)

show(p)
```