# Fixing Python Bokeh Datetime Import Formatting

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, bokeh

I'm exporting datasets from equipment logging software and am trying to use Bokeh (Python) as an interactive visual aide during analysis. Everything is working fine, except for the date/time which refuses to be imported in its current format (24/08/2022  01:40:32). I have data for every second for at least a month's worth (So dropping the date wouldn't work).

I've been playing about with Bokeh for a while now by simply ignoring the date/time and replacing it by a consecutive series (1,2,3...) and plotting it as such, but the *time* has come to fix my temporary solution and I just cant seem to figure out how to define the formatting or how to convert it. ([Bokeh documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/properties.html?highlight=datetime#bokeh.core.properties.Datetime))

Example code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show # OUTPUT_FILE FOR EXPORT (NOT USED)
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot # MULTIPLOT
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4 # COLOUR PALETTE
import pandas as pd
import external_tags as tags # TAG DEFINITIONS USED FOR CSV IMPORTING

# import csv
df = pd.read_csv("AUGUST_PS_1MIN.csv")      # testset with 1 min intervals

# TOOLS
TOOLS = "box_zoom, box_select, crosshair, reset, hover"
Figure_Title = "TESTING AUTOMATING IMPORT WITHOUT MANUAL TWEAKING"

line_width = 1.5
alpha = 1
height = 500
x = df[tags.Date_Time_UTC[0]]

# These just redirect to my imported tag definitions TAG = ["column name", "friendly name"]
fig1a = tags.PS_MH_LOAD
fig1b = tags.PS_MH_WINCH_PWR
fig1c = tags.PS_PWR_MSB1
fig1d = tags.PS_PWR_MSB2

# FIGURE A (TOP LEFT)
s1 = figure(sizing_mode="stretch_width", height=height, title="LOAD", tools=TOOLS, x_axis_type='datetime')
s1.line(x, df[fig1a[0]], color=Spectral4[0], alpha=alpha, line_width=line_width, legend_label=fig1a[1])
s1.line(x, df[fig1b[0]], color=Spectral4[1], alpha=alpha, line_width=line_width, legend_label=fig1b[1])
s1.line(x, df[fig1c[0]], color=Spectral4[2], alpha=alpha, line_width=line_width, legend_label=fig1c[1])
s1.line(x, df[fig1d[0]], color=Spectral4[3], alpha=alpha, line_width=line_width, legend_label=fig1d[1])

#### some repetitive code has been omitted here for brevity

# Define the grid
# p = gridplot([[s1, s2],[s3, s4]])

# show the results
show(s1)
```

Example of a dataset

```
2022-08-26 04:03:52.000,0,30,30,894.70751953125,-63.785041809082,-0.497732371091843,2.14258599281311,0.0307948496192694,355.496154785156,0,0,0,2.38387619901914E-05,0,102.844131469727,0.040388036519289,0.703329265117645,0,0,0.0244150012731552,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1455.31506347656,0.0106834815815091
2022-08-26 04:03:53.000,0,30,30,895.21142578125,-63.6380615234375,-0.550026297569275,2.14223098754883,0.0307948496192694,355.496154785156,0,0,0,1.45306594276917E-05,0,102.827079772949,0.0610153041779995,0.733967423439026,0,0,0.0245136469602585,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1455.31506347656,0.0106870988383889
2022-08-26 04:03:54.000,0,30,30,895.726196289063,-63.6465072631836,-0.533430516719818,2.1423876285553,0.0307948496192694,355.496154785156,0,0,0,8.71746851771604E-06,0,102.834602355957,0.0816425681114197,0.764605581760406,0,0,0.0246122926473618,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1455.31506347656,0.0106907160952687
2022-08-26 04:03:55.000,0,30,30,896.1552734375,-63.0882987976074,-0.534056782722473,2.14190745353699,0.0307948496192694,355.496154785156,0,0,0,5.21722904522903E-06,0,102.811561584473,0.10226983577013,0.795243740081787,0,0,0.024710938334465,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1455.31506347656,0.0106943333521485
2022-08-26 04:03:56.000,0,30,30,895.727600097656,-63.0707931518555,-0.515181064605713,2.14224052429199,0.0307948496192694,355.496154785156,0,0,0,3.12787688017124E-06,0,102.827545166016,0.122897103428841,0.825881898403168,0,0,0.0248095821589231,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1455.31506347656,0.0106979506090283
2022-08-26 04:03:57.000,0,30,30,895.690246582031,-63.511173248291,-0.49309903383255,2.14326453208923,0.0307948496192694,355.496154785156,0,0,0,7.10703216100228E-06,0,102.876693725586,0.143524378538132,0.856520056724548,0,0,0.0249082278460264,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1455.31506347656,0.0107015678659081
```

Any help would be appreciated. :)

**tl;dr**: how do I import/use the date and time in Bokeh when the source is formatted as follows: "2022-08-26 04:03:57"

**UPDATE**
I got it to be recognized as datetime! Still some kinks and formatting to figure out, but this is what did the trick for me:

```
x = df[tags.Date_Time_UTC[0]]
x = pd.to_datetime(x)
```

I also manually removed the trailing decimals from the seconds.

```
  2022-08-26 04:03:56.000 ->   2022-08-26 04:03:56
```

Further answers and tips are, of course, welcome. But I can continue for now!

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have imported `pandas` the easiest way to parse a string to a datetime object is [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html). This function can also parse multiple [formats using %f-string notation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

For example

```
pd.to_datetime('2022-01-01', format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

and

```
pd.to_datetime("01/01/2022 00:00:00", format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

will both result in the same datetime object.

If you want to parse a complete column of a pandas DataFrame you could use the `.iloc` method. Let's say you want to parse the first column (zero based index).

```
df.iloc[:,0] = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0], format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

should work.

The example below is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517888/bokeh-line-plot-with-string-x-value) and if you want to read the bokeh tutorial, there is one which shows how to [enable datetime axes](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps/first_steps_4.html?highlight=datetime#enabling-datetime-axes).

### Example

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

sample={'A':[pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y-%m') for x in ['2012-01','2012-02','2012-03']],'B':[7,8,9]}
source = ColumnDataSource(sample)
p = figure(width=400, height=400,  x_axis_type='datetime')
p.line(x='A', y='B', source=source, line_width=2)
output_notebook()
show(p)
```

### Output

[image: line plot with datetime x-axis]

FYI: The function [`pd.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv) has a argument `parse_dates` which calls `pd.to_datetime` while parsing the csv-file. But there are multiple options and the usage depends on the data. So you have to read the documentation because this would make this post really long.

Answer (score 0):

bokeh version 2.4.3 seems to parse your second example date: `bokeh.core.properties.Datetime().is_valid("2022-08-26 04:03:57")` returns True. However, it doesn't think your first example, `"24/08/2022 01:40:32"` is valid. This answer might help with that one, though? [Using Bokeh datetime with Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857971/using-bokeh-datetime-with-pandas)